# Accessing list of object inside an object

Tags: c#, json

I have class named `ResponseModel` and one object inside that class named `Errors` refer to the class `ErrorsResponseModel`, and that class has bunch of objects which have `List<string>` data type . I would like to know on how to accessing the `List<string>` objects without going through like: `VariableClassA.ObjectOfClassAWhichReferToTheClassB.FirstListOfString` and `VariableClassA.ObjectOfClassAWhichReferToTheClassB.SecondListOfString`, the data of `List<string>` objects comes from the JSON data.

I have tried only to access one object per one object as I am not really sure on how to do generic without going through one object per one object, which is if I update the model of class B itself, then I need to make sure that I didn't missed out the necessary checking of that newly created object inside class B.

Here is the code of the model:

```
public sealed class ResponseModel
{
    public ErrorsResponseModel Errors { get; set; }
}

public sealed class ErrorsResponseModel
{
    public List<string> Username { get; set; }
    public List<string> Password { get; set; }
    public List<string> Nickname { get; set; }
}
```

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
string jsonData = "{"Errors":{"Username":["The username field is required."],"Password":["The password field is required."],"Nickname":["The nickname field is required."]}}";

var jsonConvertedData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResponseModel>(jsonData);

var usernameErrors = jsonConvertedData.Errors.Username;

var passwordErrors = jsonConvertedData.Errors.Password;

var nicknameErrors = jsonConvertedData.Errors.Nickname;
```

I expect to loop any object of class `ErrorsResponseModel` that the length of `List<string>` inside that class is more than 0 . I can't change the response data from the JSON, as it is comes from the third party.

EDIT: I have tried the following in JavaScript and it works, how can I do the same in C#?

in C#, I return to the front end like using the following `return Json(jsonConvertedData)`, and in frontend, I do like the following:

```
$.ajax({
..... the AJAX settings

success: function (data) {
$.each(data.Errors, function (i, v) {
  if (v.length > 0) {
       console.log(v);
    }
});
}
```

The above code in Javascript is looping through the message inside each object inside `ErrorsResponseModel` and read it through to the console.

Comment: Can you please add some more details where facing the actual issue ?

Comment: Are the three lists related to each other? I.e, does `jsonConvertedData.Errors.Password[0]` and `jsonConvertedData.Errors.Nickname[0]` both apply to the user `jsonConvertedData.Errors.Username[0]`? If so, it would be easy enough to write a method that populates a list of `User` classes that each contain the related data.

Comment: Also could you please clarify what you want to get as result? Concatenation of all errors like `jsonConvertedData.Errors.Username.Concat(jsonConvertedData.Errors.Password).Concat(jsonConvertedData.Errors.Nickname)`?

Comment: Hi @AlexeiLevenkov, if I do that, does it means the same like I have to access it per one by one? Please see the edited question which I label it `EDIT`

Comment: Hi @vijaysahu, please see the edited question which I label it `EDIT`

Comment: Hi @RufusL, yes it does relate to each other, the `Password` and `Nickname` field is apply to the user of `Username`, however, please do see the edited question which I label it `EDIT` to have you more understanding on the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let `ErrorsResponseModel` inherit `Dictionary`

```
public sealed class ErrorsResponseModel : Dictionary<string, List<string>>
{
    //If you still want to access data with property.
    public List<string> Username => this["Username"];
    ...
}
```

Now you can loop through `Errors` like a normal dictionary

```
foreach (var item in jsonConvertedData.Errors)
    if(item.Value.Count > 0)
       Console.WriteLine($"{item.Key} => {item.Value[0]}");
```

---

`dynamic` is another choice

```
var jsonConvertedData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(jsonData);

foreach (var item in jsonConvertedData.Errors)
    if(item.Count > 0)
        foreach(var v in item.Value)
            Console.WriteLine(v);
```

Comment: Just what I needed. Thanks a lot @shingo

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to create a class to hold the related data, for example:

```
class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Nickname { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

Then we can make a method that populates a list of this class from the `ErrorsResponseModel` class (after first validating that the counts of all the lists are the same):

```
public List<User> GetUsers(ErrorsResponseModel errors)
{
    if (errors == null || errors.Username == null) return null;
    if (errors.Username.Count == 0) return new List<User>();

    if (errors.Nickname?.Count != errors.Password?.Count ||
        errors.Password?.Count != errors.Username.Count)
    {
        throw new InvalidDataException("Unequal number of Usernames/Passwords/Nicknames");
    }

    return errors.Username
        .Select((userName, index) =>
        new User
        {
            Name = userName,
            Nickname = errors.Nickname[index],
            Password = errors.Password[index]
        }).ToList();
}
```